# Apache Hadoop accelerator -ignite environment variable setup

Tags: hadoop, ignite

I am using apache ignite hadoop accelerator for apache hadoop.
When I use this configuration in ~/.bashrc file ignite.sh works fine but hadoop does not work and shows error.

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo

```
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/app/hadoop 
export HADOOP_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_PREFIX/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/app/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce
export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin:$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin

export IGNITE_HOME=/app/ignite2/apache-ignite-hadoop-1.9.0-bin
```

I tried to change settings.

```
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/app/hadoop
export HADOOP_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_PREFIX/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX 
export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin:$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin
```

Then hadoop works fine but ignite shows error

```
Ignite node stopped OK [uptime=00:00:02:626]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataOutputStream
```

I also tried to make soft links but did not work. Tell me if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally (for standard distributions such as Apache, Hortonworks, Cloudera) Ignite guesses all the Hadoop library locations based only on HADOOP_HOME environment variable value, thus, typically there is no need to specify the HADOOP_COMMON_HOME, HADOOP_HDFS_HOME, HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME explicitly. However, if you're using some specific Hadoop ditribution layout , you can specify these 3 variables, in which case they and only they will be used to locate the Hadoop libraries. If your Hadoop distribution requires values of these variables, that contradict to those required for Ignite, you will probably have to use different environments for Hadoop and for Ignite node processes.

Ignite will use the following libraries relative to the 3 above values:

```
${HADOOP_COMMON_HOME}/lib/*
${HADOOP_COMMON_HOME}/hadoop-common-*
${HADOOP_COMMON_HOME}/hadoop-auth-*

${HADOOP_HDFS_HOME}/lib/*
${HADOOP_HDFS_HOME}/hadoop-hdfs-*

${HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME}/lib/*
${HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME}/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common*
${HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME}/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core*

+ ${HADOOP_USER_LIBS}, if defined.
```

Comment: Thank you.That worked. I removed all variables other than `hadoop home`  then both ignite and hadoop started working.

Answer (score 0):

The exception means that Ignite node does not have Hadoop libraries on classpath. Please refer to Hadoop Accelerator installation instructions: https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/installing-on-apache-hadoop

Comment: ` echo $CLASSPATH
:/app/derby/lib/derby.jar:/app/derby/lib/derbytools.jar:/app/hadoop/lib/*:.:/app/hive/lib/*:.:/app/hazelcast-3.7.5/lib/hazelcast-all-3.7.5.jar:/app/hadoop/bin:/app/ignite2/apache-ignite-hadoop-1.9.0-bin/bin:/app/hadoop/share/hadoop/common:/app/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce:/app/ignite2/apache-ignite-hadoop-1.9.0-bin/libs/*:.`

Comment: Prashant, what Hadoop distribution do you use? Exact answer to your question depends on that.